# Loading USDZ for ARKit (not a QLPreview) Material Properties

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, usdz

I'm trying to load a `usdz` file into ARKkit that has glass transparency on one of its materials. When I put the model into a `QLPreviewController` the glass renders properly. The problem is I want to render the glass in a `SCNScene` with ARKit, not `QLPreview`, the glass material is black when I load it into a SCNScene. It is also black when I preview it in Xcode.

Not sure what `QLPreview` is doing, or if I'm doing something wrong with my lighting in my scene. I've removed all my custom lights and just have `autoenablesDefaultLighting` set to `true`. Then I set each material's lighting model to be `PhysicallyBased`. But still just black.

Anybody know what I need to do to render the same way `QLPreview` does? Do I need to unpack the usdz to get the transparency texture and set that manually?

Thanks!

Comment: Update: Had to set the transparency value manually on the material, for some reason that isn't processed with the png.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to create a glass in SceneKit is to use Phong shading model (not a PBR). At the moment there are no PBR glass in SceneKit framework, so you need to use a fake one. For making a `fake glass` you need to create a `SCNMaterial` with the following properties:

```
let material = SCNMaterial()

material.lightingModel = .phong
material.diffuse.contents = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 1)
material.diffuse.intensity = 0.9
material.specular.contents = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1)
material.specular.intensity = 1.0
material.reflective.contents = UIImage(named: "fileName.png")
material.reflective.intensity = 2.0

material.transparencyMode = .dualLayer
material.fresnelExponent = 2.2
material.isDoubleSided = true
material.blendMode = .alpha
material.shininess = 100
material.transparency.native = 0.7
material.cullMode = .back
```

`.fresnelExponent` property determines the intensity of reflections in a surface based on its angle relative to the viewer. A higher Fresnel exponent increases the visibility of reflections when the material is viewed from a shallow angle. It's not an IOR (Fresnel's Index of Refraction).

> PBR glass or PBR water objects are very expensive at render time due to ray-tracing technology.

[image]

If you need a partial transparency of your object – just use `transparent` slot in `Material Inspector` to load a B&W mask for transparent/opaque regions.