# USDZ file does not work properly on SceneKit

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, realitykit

I am trying to load a `.usdz` model with transparency in SceneKit. It works perfectly in RealityKit but in the case of SceneKit I only get a black sphere.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In order to see a material of USDZ model in SceneKit just turn the default lighting on.

```
@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
```

If you need to learn more about transparency in SceneKit, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52859549/loading-usdz-for-arkit-not-a-qlpreview-material-properties/52863412#52863412) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52021860/how-to-render-a-3d-model-with-semi-transparent-textures-in-xcode/52022375#52022375).

---

P.S.

Also, [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56828648/how-to-add-material-to-modelentity-programatically-in-realitykit/56849454#56849454) about the similarities between SceneKit and RealityKit shaders.